# Mongodb find distinct value with range

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql, aggregation-framework, nosql-aggregation

I have a mongodb database where I have two collections - `elements` and `properties`. The `elements` look something like this -

```
{ _id: "someElementId", name: "Iron", type: "metal" }
```

And the `properties` look like this -

```
{ _id: "somePropertyId", propName: "molecular weight", propType: "number", unit: null }
```

Each `element` can have multiple `properties` and a value corresponding to the property. For example `iron` can have properties `molecular weight`, `color`, `atomic weight` etc.

For that I created another collection where I stored the element id and corresponding property id and its value -

```
{ elementId: "someElementId", propId:  "somePropertyId", value: 55.845 }
```

Now I want to find the names of all the unique properties and the range of their values that occurs in the database. So for example, if 1 is the lowest value corresponding the above property and 100 is the highest value, I want something like -

```
[ { name: "molecular weight", range: { min: 1, max: 100 } } ]
```

I can get the distinct properties and iterate over them to get the range, but I was wondering if there's a better way. Or maybe this table structure is not efficient enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if this would work for you:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$propId",
      min: {
        $min: "$value"
      },
      max: {
        $max: "$value"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "properties",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "name"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$name"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      "name": "$name.propName",
      "range": {
        "min": "$min",
        "max": "$max"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XRxyVAj_GEX)

Comment: Thanks. But I have to get the `name` field from the `properties` collection according to the `id`

Comment: I see now, my bad. I've updated the answer, please take a look!